# How to handle Stripe currencies

Tags: stripe-payments

We have a platform where **users** can PAY **experts** for their help (for example, create a logo for my company). Anyone can ask for help and anyone can help others.

• If you want to receive payments in our platform, you need to follow the **Stripe Standard Onboarding** process.

• Users pay other users through a **Stripe Direct Charge**

The payments are always in **USD** ($2, $5 or $10 USDs).

We have users from Mexico, USA, Colombia, etc., and Stripe accepts payments with cross currencies. However, some cards issuers do not accept charges from other currencies... for example, my card is from Mexico and my bank do not accept charges in "USD". I received this

```
"decline_code": "currency_not_supported"
"message": "Your card is not supported for this currency."
```

What we need is that anyone can pay in "USD" from anywhere and that the bank do not reject the transaction. I think that maybe we can do conversions in our server side... but I'm not sure if there is a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

USD is generally supported for most credit cards in Mexico (not American Express, though): https://stripe.com/docs/currencies?presentment-currency=MX

If a customer's bank declines a payment for that or any other reason, you would need to ask for other payment details to use.

Alternatively, you can present the payment in a more familiar local currency and it will settle in the currency of the connected account:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/currencies#currency-conversions
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/currencies#application-fees-for-direct-charges
https://stripe.com/docs/currencies/conversions#avoiding-currency-conversions

Note there may be cross-border and/or foreign exchange fees in some scenarios.

Comment: Thank you Nolan for your help. I saw a payment attempt with "USD" presentment currency with a Mexican Mastercard... it was declined (currency_not_supported). So, we updated to "MXN" and asked to try again, and it worked. Do you know what could happened?